# How to modify configuration file which is residing inside a JAR

Tags: java, jar

I would like to modify the configuration file which is residing inside the JAR. How to modify the configuration properties files which is residing inside a JAR file without Extracting?

Comment: *When* do you want to modify it?

Comment: We are building the JAR for running the AWS SWF activities. Periodically we have to change the SWF Domain and URL for the security reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JAR is just a ZIP file. You can use any tool to manipulate the contents. In Java, there is the class [`java.util.zip.ZipFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) which you can use in combination with other classes of this package to manipulate the contents of the JAR.

But even the standard `jar` tool has options to update a JAR file. Read the documentation for how this can be done.